# Refresh parent page from prettyPhoto iframe

Tags: iframe, prettyphoto

I have a parent page that calls an iframe modal window as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
                            $(document).ready(function(){
                                $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
                            });

</script>
```

When the iframe is closed, I want the parent page to refresh.

What code do I need to add to the iframe? Do I need to create a callback function on the  parent page first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look closely at the source, prettyphoto wraps the iframe in a div that contains all the buttons. the only part that is iframed is the actual content. The close button is contained in the parent page. You will need to add an event handler to `.pp_close` click event.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
  $(".pp_close").click(function () {
    document.location.reload(true);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I can see that now but I must be doing something wrong, I've added: 
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">       $(".pp_close").click(function() {          document.location.reload(true);       });            
</script> to the parent page and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: you still need to put it inside of the document.ready(). i'll update my answer...

Comment: Hi Juventus18, when I tried that it actually closes and then refreshes BUT shows the dialog window again. What I managed to do was edit jquery.prettyPhoto.js editing the lines: $('a.pp_close').bind('click',function(){$.prettyPhoto.close();clearHashtag();document.location.reload(true);return true;}). Seems to work, not sure if it's semantically correct but it'll do for now.

Answer (score 2):

I did it via callback:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto(
    {
     modal: true, /*So it can be closed only with the button*/
     callback: function(){
       document.location.reload(true);
    }                       
   })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        window.parent.refreshPage();
        window.parent.$.prettyPhoto.close();
    });
</script>
```

the on the page you opened the iframe have this there

```
window.refreshPage = function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.reload();
    }, 500);
};
```